# Getting "path.resolve is not a function" in nexjs while using dotenv

Tags: reactjs, next.js, process, environment-variables, dotenv

I am using dotenv in a TypeScript (ts) file to import environment files and group my environment variables, and perform some functions. I need to use dotenv because I am using environment variables to run scripts, like starting Docker with some secrets and running migrations. However, as soon as my Next.js application starts, I get the following error.

variables.ts

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: path.resolve is not a function
  2 | import { z } from "zod";
  3 | import dotenv from "dotenv"; 
> 4 | dotenv.config({ path: "../.env" });
  5 | 
  6 | export const env = createEnv({
  7 | server: {
```

this is how I am using the env in my variables.ts

```
PGHOST: process.env.PGHOST
```

I was previously getting `fs error` so I fixed it by using this.

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  }
```

can anyone help me with this issue and how to fix it?
or is there any better way to configure env variables in next.js?